# Google Analytics Report Filter not working

Tags: google, google-analytics

I want to filter myself out of the Google Analytics report, so I go to Admin->Filter, then exclude my IP addresses.

But when I check the report, the visits from my country are still the same. I am sure the IP address is correct. It seems the filter doesn't take effect. Why is that?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot one thing, my site is using CDN...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

profile filter doesn't apply to past data...

Answer (score 1):

Pls Tell me you have static ip or dynamic ip?

If you have a dynamic id then every time your ip range shoulf be change.

so pls check ones again.

In my domain it is work good.

Comment: it is static. After I added the filter, do I need any steps to make it work??

Comment: Sorry, I forgot one thing, my site is using CDN, I think that should be the reason I can't filter out myself, right??

Comment: Am I missing something? I just tried to create a country filter e.g. Hong Kong, but when I go back to the Location report, it still show Hong Kong in the list..